# How do I read multiple JSON lines (line-delimited)?

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I get the below json from a url:

```
{"bytes": 5043, "name": "a", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"}
{"bytes": 0, "name": "b", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"}
{"bytes": 11590, "name": "c", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"}
```

I want to return the bytes for each line. Using Jackson I've tried parsing it as follows(note: json is saved to file for testing):

```
package JsonRead;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTreeModelLogStorage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(new File("JsonRead/json2.json"));

            JsonNode logStorageNode = root;

            for(JsonNode node : logStorageNode){
                String bytesUsed = node.path("bytes").asText();
                System.out.println("Bytes Used: " + bytesUsed);
            }

        } catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("IO Exception " + e );
        }
    }
}
```

This returns the following:

```
Bytes Used: 
Bytes Used: 
Bytes Used: 
Bytes Used:
```

If I then change my for loop to the following I can see I'm returning the first line of json:

```
for(JsonNode node : logStorageNode){
            String json = node.asText();
            System.out.println("json: " + a);
}
```

How do I real the bytes for all lines of json?

Comment: The JSON you posted isn't valid : the JSON spec doesn't allow multiple objects side by side like this. I suppose you're receiving an array? If so, that must be your problem : you should handle the `root` as a `JsonArray` rather than a `JsonNode` and loop on its content

Comment: I found this blog quite useful: [Line-delimited JSON with Jackson](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/line-delimited-json-with-jackson-69c9e4cb6c00).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks guys. That was a big help.

I edited the try slightly to suit my needs. Here's what I ended up with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try(
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("JsonRead/json2.json");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        ) {
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Vault vlt = mapper.readValue(currentLine, Vault.class);
                System.out.println(vlt.getBytes());
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The content you posted isn't valid JSON: the JSON spec doesn't allow multiple objects side by side like this.

If you encounter such text (it can't be considered JSON), you will want to split it over a delimiter so that each substring is a valid JSON object which you will be able to parse.
In your case, it seems that linefeed is a valid delimiter, but you should make sure that your JSON objects will never contain any linefeed. If that's the case, you can parse your text as follows :

```
try(
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("JsonRead/json2.json");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
) {
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        JsonNode logStorageNode = mapper.readTree(currentLine);
        // [...] carry on with your current code.
    }
}
```

---

I first assumed you were receiving an array instead :

```
[
    {"bytes": 5043, "name": "a", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"},
    {"bytes": 0, "name": "b", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"},
    {"bytes": 11590, "name": "c", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"}
]
```

In that case, you should loop on its content :

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(new File("JsonRead/json2.json"));

if (!root.isArray()) {
    throw WhateverException("A JSON Array is expected");
}

// a cast to ArrayNode would be possible, but isn't necessary
// as per the design of jackson's JsonNode
Iterator<JsonNode> it = root.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode logStorageNode = it.next();

    // [...] carry on with your current code.
}
```

Comment: It's not an array. Is it possible it's returning a text file containing lines for json?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but then the file content can't be parsed as a single JSON object (and the content-type of the response probably isn't application/json). If each line of the file contain a single JSON object and the JSON objects themselves don't contain any linefeed, you could iterate over the lines of the file and parse a JSON object from the content of each of them. I you confirm this I'll update my answer to handle such a file.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of checking the response type. It's binary/octet-stream.

Each line does contain a linefeed e.g:
    "{"bytes": 5043, "name": "a", "timestamp": "11-Apr-2017 12:11:51", "ds": "Lab1"}[\n]"

Comment: Since Java 8 [Files.lines(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).